# iOS navigate from inital view to second view from the last view

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

Below you see my view hierarchy. The view with green color is the last view. From the last view I want show another view, indicated by the black arrow.

However when the user wants to navigate back from this view, the initial view (indicated by yellow arrow) should be presented. I could make a segue from last view to the "black arrow" view. But how can I show the initial view (yellow arrow) when user goes back?

[image]

Comment: is it embedded with navigation controller ?

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov "the initial view" - yes, the "black arrow view" - I am not sure, it is a table view controller and I just connected it with the initial view using storyboard segue.

Comment: so simple access that viewC and then add..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**METHOD1:** Well, then it depends on your segues, if all of them is **push** type, then your green VC will be embedded too. If it is, then you can navigate through all your hierarchy via `[self.navigationController popToViewController:desiredViewController animated:YES]`.

**Here what this method does:** Pops view controllers until the specified view controller is at the top of the navigation stack.

[Reference: UINavigationController Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**METHOD2:** If you still want to use modal presentation, you could create *weak* `delegate` property to bind your greenController with controller, which presented it (or use NSNotificationCenter to listen your **dismiss** modal view controller event). Once user pressed on dismissing, controller which presented greenController redirects it with no animation to yellow one. It will create the illusion that once you dismissed your controller underneath is yellowController. However, it still depends on your transition needs between yellow-green controllers.

Comment: the green VC is modal.

Comment: You could switch it to push one and set your custom transition (ios7 feature) to make it look like modal presentation.